# Kate textbody/field vanished

Tags: kate

My kate textbody/field spontaneously vanished... I can still click in the text field and if a file is loaded I can type and it changes the file. I didn't knowingly change anything in Ubuntu or kate; this happened when I tried to open a new textfile via the "New" button in the drop down menu.

I did the usual restart and tried to reinstall via

```
sudo apt-get remove kate
sudo apt-get install kate
```

This installs `kate 4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa63`, which it claims is the most up to date version.

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS

[image: Kate without text field]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "My kate textbody/field spontaneously vanished... I can still click in the text field and if a file is loaded I can type and it changes the file." You're say the text field vanished but you can still type in it and edit files you open? Then what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: See the picture. I can type, I can use all menu buttons - but there is no textfield displayed (So I dont see what I type...)

Comment: Can you highlight (select) the text you typed? Does doing so make the selected text visible?

Comment: No, in fact as soon as the mouse courser hovers over the textfield it vanishes.

Comment: On my system, Kubuntu 18.04, I have the following files in ~/.config: katemetainfos, katemoderc, katepartrc, katerc, kateschemarc, katesyntaxhighlightingrc, katevirc. With kate not running, rename these files to something else and restart kate in case that helps.

Comment: I also have `~/.local/share/kate`.

Comment: Great! Changing the kate* files in .config did nothing, but when I renamed kate `mv anonymous.katesession anonymous.katesession_old` in `~/.local/share/kate` I got back, a different looking, but working kate! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, removing the program and reinstalling it may not achieve much if the issue is because a user inadvertently changes some feature, via the graphical user interface. In other words, some file in the user's home folder has been changed and that file is not replaced by removing and reinstalling the program.

Here, since the application is Kate, I ran `find -iname "*kate*"` from the home folder.

```
$ find -iname "*kate*"
./.config/katemetainfos
./.config/katesyntaxhighlightingrc
./.config/katemoderc
./.config/katepartrc
./.config/kateschemarc
./.config/katevirc
./.config/katerc
./.cache/khelpcenter/help/__en__kate__index.docbook
./.cache/kate
./.local/share/RecentDocuments/kate.desktop
./.local/share/kate
./.local/share/kate/anonymous.katesession
./.local/share/kate/sessions/Mine.katesession
./.local/share/kxmlgui5/kate
./.local/share/kxmlgui5/kate/kateui.rc
$
```

Renaming all these files, excluding those in *~/.cache*, would remove all user-modified configurations. Then, by a process of trial and error, it should be possible to identify the problematic file.

In the present case, the user found that renaming *./.local/share/kate/anonymous.katesession* to *anonymous.katesession_old* and restarting Kate restored the initial functionality albeit at a price of losing some settings.